# Trilinos: Extracting a submatrix of an Epetra CrsMatrix

Tags: trilinos

Given a distributed Epetra CrsMatrix $A$, along with a a list of rows, a list of columns and a processor ID, I would like to extract a sub-matrix $A_{sub}$, all the entries of which should be stored on the specified processor.

I think this may be done with Import/Export object with suitably defined maps but I cannot seem to find an example.

Comment: This is question best asked on the Trilinos/Epetra mailing lists.

Comment: I understand your point. But I find that their mailing list to be highly unresponsive to questions. However if this question is considered off-topic to Computational Science I will gladly delete it.

Comment: Yes, the Computational Science StackExchange policy says that questions specific to individual software packages are off-topic here. Sorry.

Comment: I should add that if you can't get anyone to respond on the Trilinos mailing lists, then the likelihood that they will respond here is not larger either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I have found a solution. Here is a minimal working example in Python.

```
from PyTrilinos import Epetra, Galeri
comm = Epetra.PyComm()

my_id = comm.MyPID()

if my_id ==0:
    my_range = [0, 1, 5 , 7]
else:
    my_range = []

subset_map = Epetra.Map(-1, my_range , 0, comm)

nx, ny = 4

GaleriList = {"n"  : nx * ny,
              "nx" : nx,
              "ny" : ny
              }
Map    = Galeri.CreateMap("Linear", comm, GaleriList)
Matrix = Galeri.CreateCrsMatrix("Recirc2D", Map, GaleriList)

importer = Epetra.Import(subset_map, Matrix.Map())

Submatrix = Epetra.CrsMatrix(Epetra.Copy, subset_map,subset_map, 5)
Submatrix.Import(Matrix, importer, Epetra.Insert)
Submatrix.FillComplete()
```